# Replacing value input by user with value assigned with state in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I have a reactstrap Input field

```
        <Input
          onChange={handlePriceInputChange}
          type="number"
          defaultValue={price}
          innerRef={register("price", { required: true })}
        ></Input>
```

which I am filling with a default `""` state called `price` in `defaultValue`.

```
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
```

I set this value with a function in `onChange`

```
  const handlePriceInputChange = (ev) => {
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.value));
  };
```

and also clicking some div containers trigger a function `handleSelectedBox`

```
  const handleSelectedBox = (ev) => {
    setSelected(ev.target.getAttribute("data-boxprice"));
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.getAttribute("data-price")));
  };
```

When I fill the input field manually and then trigger the buttons that should trigger `handleSelectedBox`, the state `price` changes, but the value stays the same on the client-side.

**How could I force**  `handleSelectedBox` **to change the value within input even if such value was set manually?**

Comment: It doesn't work when you just use value={price} instead of defaultValue ?

Comment: if I use value={price} then I can't change that value manually, is fixed

Comment: oops, it does work like that, thank you

Comment: Haha cool no problem bro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to use value instead of defaultValue :

```
        <Input
          onChange={handlePriceInputChange}
          type="number"
          value={price}
          innerRef={register("price", { required: true })}
        ></Input>
```